# Laravel updateExistingPivot get column own value

Tags: laravel

I want to update a pivot column, but I need to access its own value

is there a way to access it, here is the code and the operation that I need to perform:

(supply_early's value - $winner_tender_volume)

```
$config_team_product->supplies()->updateExistingPivot($tender->year_id, [
         'supply_early' => "here I need supply_early's column value" - $winner_tender_volume
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

please try using newPivotQuery(), this method make the query applied directly on the pivot table:

```
  $config_team_product->supplies()->newPivotQuery()
    ->update(['supply_early' => 
DB::raw( 'CONCAT(supply_early, '-',?)',[$winner_tender_volume]));
```